# In NetBeans, how to import in eclipse projects from subversion without having to do a second checkout?

Tags: svn, netbeans, import

In NetBeans, there is an option to do Team -> Subversion -> Checkout.  However, I am worried that if I do this, it will save a second copy of the SVN folder (I already have one that exists on my desktop).  I only want to get to the choice: Team -> Import for repository, and just import a single project.  Is there an option that uses the checked out svn folder already on my desktop or do I need to check it out separately from NetBeans and use additional space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the checkout window, log in to the subversion repository and then there will be an option to browse for the specific folders you want to check out.  Leaving it empty will mean you will want to checkout the whole svn folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are muddling 'import a project' with 'import from svn'.

If the source for the 'Eclipse project' is checked out onto your local disk, NetBeans can see it and perform svn actions against it, via the Favorites window.

When you import the Eclipse project into NetBeans, the IDE has to create different meta-data files that describe your project. If you place these new meta-data files in the source tree of your existing project, the new files will appear as 'new' files as far as SVN is concerned.

If you using Maven to describe your project to Eclipse, you do not need to 'import' the project into NetBeans... NetBeans understands the maven pom.xml... you just need to 'File->Open Project' and give the path to the directory that holds your projects pom.xml file.